# placing a list with indices (changing length) after a hierarchy of lists to change the values

Tags: python, list, hierarchy, indices

I have the following hierarchy of lists:

```
boundaries = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [[0, 4, 8, 7], [4, 3, 9, 8]]],
              [[2, 1, 6, 5]], [[1, 0, 7, 6]]]
```

Two lists with indices:

```
index1 = [1, 0, 2]      # is the same as [1][0][2]  
index2 = [1, 1, 0, 1]   # is the same as [1][1][0][1]
```

However, when I try to do the description below, it does not work.

```
boundaries[index1] = 45  
boundaries[index2] = 45
```

This is not possible, because `index1` and `index2` are lists.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bad design .... but ... you could iteratively descend into your sublists like so:

```
boundaries = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [[0, 4, 8, 7], [4, 3, 9, 8]]],
              [[2, 1, 6, 5]], [[1, 0, 7, 6]]] 

index1 = [1, 0, 2]      # is the same as [1][0][2]  
index2 = [1, 1, 0, 1]   # is the same as [1][1][0][1]


def iterateively_descent(idx, l, val):
    # iteratively descent until the last sublist
    for k in idx[:-1]:
        l = l[k] 
    # set the value of the last sublist
    l[idx[-1]] = val

print(boundaries)

iterateively_descent(index1,boundaries,45)
print(boundaries)

iterateively_descent(index2,boundaries,145)
print(boundaries)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [[0, 4, 8, 7], [4, 3, 9, 8]]],
 [[2, 1, 6, 5]], [[1, 0, 7, 6]]]

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 45, 8, 9], [[0, 4, 8, 7], [4, 3, 9, 8]]],
 [[2, 1, 6, 5]], [[1, 0, 7, 6]]]

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 45, 8, 9], [[0, 145, 8, 7], [4, 3, 9, 8]]], 
 [[2, 1, 6, 5]], [[1, 0, 7, 6]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts were the same as Patrick suggested, which would do the trick but seems a bit strange. Have you considered using numpy arrays instead? If that's an option, then it might make your life a bit easier. You could then do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

boundaries = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]])
index = (0, 1, 1)
print("Before:")
print(boundaries)
boundaries[index] = 42
print("After: ")
print(boundaries)
```

Output would be:

```
Before:
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]]
After:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4 42  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]]
```

Main difference here is that you'd need to install numpy (not sure if that's an option), and that your indexes have to be tuples (I don't think numpy allows indexing using lists).